# Porque NetBeans no reconoce getApplicationContext()?

Tags: java, netbeans

algo muy raro que me pasa, es que intento colocar getApplicationContext() y me dice que

> "cannot find symbol"

le hago la importacion correspondiente y no da error

```
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
```

Para que entiendan, me funciona el mediaplayer, puedo crear un mediaplayer de android, pero no puedo hacer funcionar eso, porque? espero que alguien sepa gracias

El codigo fuente donde sucede este problema es el siguiente
package bfhsoftware.sonidoambiental;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 *
 * @author bfhsoftware
 */
public class ReproductorAndroid extends reproductor{
    private static MediaPlayer reproductor = null;
    OnCompletionListener escuchar = sedetienelamusica();
    public ReproductorAndroid() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void empezar(String proximotema) {        
        super.empezar(proximotema);
        //
        if ((reproductor == null)){
            try {
                if (proximotema.equals("")){                    
                    System.out.println(proximotema);
                    //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+
                    //Uri myUri = Uri.parse(proximotema);
                    reproductor = new MediaPlayer();                 
                    reproductor.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(proximotema)); 

                    reproductor.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)                                        
                    reproductor.setOnCompletionListener(escuchar);
                    reproductor.start();
                    System.out.println("deberia estar reproduciendo");
                }
            } catch(Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("error al reproducir");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());        
            }
        }
        reproduciendo = (reproductor != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void parar() {
        /* Llamamos a la implementación común de parada */
        super.parar();
        /* Implementamos aquí el método en android */
    }

    @Override
    public void pausa() {
        /* Llamamos a la implementación común de pausa */
        super.pausa();
        /* Implementamos aquí el método en android */
    }

    private OnCompletionListener sedetienelamusica() {
        reiniciar();
        reproducir();
        return null;
    }
    private void reiniciar(){
        reproduciendo = false;
        if (reproductor != null)
            reproductor.stop();
        reproductor = null;
    }
    public static void displayExceptionMessage(Context context, String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

en la linea reproductor.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(proximotema));  el complilador me dice que getApplicationContext no se reconoce como simbolo, he probado en netbeans y en intellij idea comunity version.
 Para mi el código esta bien ingresado, para mi el problema es la plataforma, no es Android donde lo ejecuto, como colocar esta sintaxis y compilarla, y que solo se ejecutase si el sistema operativo no es android?

Comment: ahi lo agregue, disculpa por no ponerlo antes, el codigo esta bien ingresado, para mi el problema es el entorno, no es android, como colocar esta sintaxis y compilarla, y que solo se ejecutase si el sistema operativo no es android?

Comment: Prueba a hacer `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` y dime si sigues teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: es el mismo problema! "Cannot find simbol"

Comment: Prueba a añadir `import android.app.Activity;` y ¿en qué línea exacta da el error?

Comment: es todo lo mismo, si da el mismo error, no es un problema de código para mi entender

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" es un error de compilación que ocurre cuando el compilador trata de encontrar la definición de un identificador pero no la encuentra. El error es algo en el código: quizás el nombre no se ha escrito bien, o la variable se está usando fuera de su contexto/alcance, o falta importar alguna clase,... puede ser un sola cosa o una combinación de varias. Ahora que has añadido el código, seguro que alguien te ayuda a encontrar la solución.

Comment: no es de código, es un error generico eso, en idea intellij me daba otro error distinto. por eso lo publico aquí. Si miras el código no hay error tal, cierto?

Comment: Que no haya un error aparente en el código no quiere decir que no sea un error en el código. Mira por ejemplo [esta pregunta de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28562595/3695983), es el mismo problema que tienes, el código está bien... pero faltaba añadir el `getActivity()` (como te sugería en otro comentario).

Comment: Al heredar de reproductor se ve que es una clase y no una actividad, con lo cual, al no heredar de ActionBarActivity no puedes acceder a getActivityContext(). Has pensado en pasarle el contexto a través del constructor de la clase??? Si lo haces así, puedes crear un atributo tipo Context en tu clase e igualarlo en el constructor

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Esa parece una buena opción. Pon una respuesta con el código de la pregunta adaptado a lo que dices a ver si le funciona.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dado que no estás heredando de ActionBarActivity no puedes acceder al método getActivityContext().

Una opción que tienes es pasarle a esta clase (a través del constructor) el contexto de la actividad en el momento que la creas. Para ello, tendrás que indicar que, en el constructor, recibes un objeto tipo Context.

Además de ésto, tienes que declarar un objeto tipo Context global a tu clase para poder igualarlo en el constructor y así poder utilizarlo en otros métodos de tu clase.

Se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 *
 * @author bfhsoftware
 */
public class ReproductorAndroid extends reproductor{
private static MediaPlayer reproductor = null;
private static Context contexto;  //Declaramos un objeto tipo Context para almacenar el que nos van a pasar por el constructor
OnCompletionListener escuchar = sedetienelamusica();
public ReproductorAndroid(Context cont) {  //Indicamos que recibimos contexto
    super();
    contexto = cont;  //Ya tenemos el contexto para utilizarlo en esta clase
}

@Override
public void empezar(String proximotema) {        
    super.empezar(proximotema);
    //
    if ((reproductor == null)){
        try {
            if (proximotema.equals("")){    
...
```

A la hora de crear un objeto lo vas a tener que hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
ReproductorAndroid repro = new ReproductorAndroid(getActivityContext());
```

Comment: dale gracias!! es la única manera de hacerlo funcionar así! dale gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

> Porque NetBeans no reconoce getApplicationContext()?

**En realidad [getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) es un método del Android SDK** que devuelve el contexto del objeto Aplicación único global del proceso actual.

Este método podría usarse si Netbeans tuviera instalado el Android Plugin (como se realizaba en Eclipse), sin embargo estos plugins ya son obsoletos y lo recomendado oficialmente para desarrollar Android es [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio).

---

En realidad lo que necesitas es el contexto,

> ¿Que hacer cuando tu clase no extiende de Activity, AppCompatActivity,
>   etc.?

En este caso la opción es enviar el contexto a instanciar la clase, para esto se modifica el constructor:

```
public class ReproductorAndroid extends reproductor{

    ...
    ...

    private Context context;

    public ReproductorAndroid(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        super();
    }

    ...
```

de esta forma puedes usar el contexto usando la variable `context`, ahora para instanciar la clase ReproductorAndroid (el uso de `getApplicationContext()` es más "ligero"):

```
ReproductorAndroid repro = new ReproductorAndroid(getApplicationContext());
```